# How to trigger a Google Cloud Build build steps with a Pull Request?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I have configured a CI pipeline using a cloudbuild.yaml file. I'm trying to launch this pipeline with Pull Requests. It seems that the provided build triggers: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds are not allowing this option. Is there a way to use webhooks to overcome this limitation? Like sending an HTTP request after a pull request event to cloud builds topic and configure a cloud function as a subscriber to launch the pipeline.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Build Github App does builds on pull request: https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github

There are three ways to run builds

- Manually: through API/gcloud
- (Beta) Build Triggers: configurable through Google Cloud Console
- (Alpha) Github App: builds automatically on changes to repo and pull
  requests

These can all be used independently or in combination with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I find that the Github App is not answering perfectly my need. I don't know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to do: clone the github repo to my local machine, do some changes, push all my commits after finishing to the the repo.The push for sure will launch the build. But, when I go to the repo after my push and try to create a pull request for the new branch I just pushed, the pull request was created without launching the pipeline again.

Comment: There is a note in the documentation: "Note: When you merge your changes, the Google Cloud Build app builds your code again. But the build details of this second build are not displayed in the Checks tab. Go to the Build history page in GCP Console to view all your Cloud Build builds.'"

Comment: it would be nice and useful to get a substitution variable available with the PR number, I hope it's on the roadmap

Answer (score 0):

A completed pull request is merged into an upstream branch (master, release, or another name). https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-a-pull-request

You can set the Google Cloud Build trigger (in Google Cloud Console) type to "Branch" and enter the relevant branch. Choose Cloud Build configuration file as your build configuration and enter your cloudbuild.yaml file location.